# How to set session time out on browser close in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to set `<%= session.getMaxInactiveInterval() %>` on browser close event or `beforeunload` event of window.

```
$(window).bind('unload', function(eventObject) {
    <%= session.getMaxInactiveInterval() %>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one JSP named getMaxInactiveInterval.jsp with your code :

`<%= session.getMaxInactiveInterval() %>`

and send a request to this jsp : http://sample.com/getMaxInactiveInterval.jsp